# How to find unique value and return corresponding max value?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like following:

```
X1 X2
a  1 
a  2 
a  3
b  4
b  5
b  1
c  4
c  4
c  6
d  1
d  0
e  6
e  8
e  9
```

Preferred output  data frame returns a unique value from the first column and the corresponding max value from the second column, like following.

```
X1 X2
a  3
b  5
c  6
d  1
e  9
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with one of the group by operations.  In `base R`, `aggregate` does this

```
aggregate(X2~X1, df1, max)
#  X1 X2
#1  a  3
#2  b  5
#3  c  6
#4  d  1
#5  e  9
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(X1) %>%
    summarise(X2= max(X2))
```

---

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(X2= max(X2)), by = X1]
```

A faster option would be to `order` the 'X2' in descending and select the first observation for each 'X1'

```
setDT(df1)[order(-X2, X1), head(.SD, 1), by = X1]
```